# Dynamically populated UL items not clickable the first time, fine after that

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-lists

I have a jQuery function that takes input and uses it to filter a list of links. When anything is typed, the function empties an existing UL and then populates it with new LI elements, each of which includes a link. The links are wired up with jQuery's "click" method.

Those resulting links *are* clickable, but only if the user first clicks anywhere else on the page outside of the input box. If the user tries to click a link immediately after the list is populated, the link does not work.

Possible hint? If I instead right-click the link and choose "Inspect Element", it shows the outer UL as the active element, *not* the LI I clicked on. If I click anywhere else first and then inspect the element, the LI *is* the active element.

Also, if I skip the step that empties the UL and instead just append to the existing list, all the links work as expected.

Anyway, the fact that the UL seems to be "on top" immediately after the new list is populated seems to indicate why the links don't get clicked. The question therefore is *why* does the UL receive the focus like that (or at least until something--anything--on the page is clicked)?

Comment: Does it matter which browser you use?

Comment: a quick comment usually when you're dynamically adding or removing content and then want to have handlers on that content, they usually do not work because the DOM has already been created and is changed on the fly. You have to bind the handlers to the selector using 

`.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) ) ej: $(ul).on('click', 'li a', function(){
//code
})`

Although this may not be the source of your problem it could help.

The .on() documentation for those interested:
[link](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Behavior is the same in both Chrome and Firefox. Have not tried other browsers yet. I have tried using .on(), but this always produces an error. Here is the original line of code: `node.find('.refine-title a').click(jQuery.proxy(this._onCheckboxClicked, this));`  Here it is using ".on":  `node.find('.refine-title a').on('click', jQuery.proxy(this._onCheckboxClicked, this));`  Am I doing anything wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *.on* (previously *.live*) method instead of *.click* that way it will wire up to anything that is added to the DOM automatically:

```
//instead of:
$('.abc').click(function() { alert('hi'); });

//use this:
$('.abc').on('click', function() { alert('hi'); });
```

[jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I have tried using .on(), but this always produces an error. Here is the original line of code: `node.find('.refine-title a').click(jQuery.proxy(this._onCheckboxClicked, this));`  Here it is using ".on":  `node.find('.refine-title a').on('click', jQuery.proxy(this._onCheckboxClicked, this));`  Am I doing anything wrong there?

Answer (score -1):

You could simulate a click on the UL element's parent (after adding list items), like this:

```
$("#idOfUl").parent().click();
```

This doesn't *really* solve your problem - it's just a possible workaround.

Comment: Workarounds are poor coding practice if a proper method of dealing with it it out there, not to say it wouldn't work, but this leads to poor code and practices - just my 2 cents.

Comment: @naspinski I agree - workarounds shouldn't be used if there is a proper solution.  In this case, there probably is a proper way to fix it, but if there wasn't, then of course a workaround would be the only option.

Comment: I tried just just for kicks, but it did not make any difference.